# Unable to use OpenGL ARB_gpu_shader_int64 extension with Mesa

Tags: amd-graphics, opengl, radeon, mesa

I am working on OpenGL shaders, and I need uint64_t types, etc...
However, when I do glxinfo, this extension is not in the list.

I am using Mesa 18.0.5, and [this page](https://www.mesa3d.org/relnotes/17.1.0.html) tells that the extension is supported for radeonsi drivers from 17.1.0.

My GPU is a AMD Radeon HD 8730M. I am using the `radeon` driver, but switching to `amdgpu` is not helping.

**Question**: how can I achieve to use uint64 in my shaders? By switching to another driver? By updating Mesa? Or is my GPU too old?

The shader I try to compile:

```
#version 450
#extension GL_ARB_gpu_shader5 : enable
#extension GL_ARB_gpu_shader_int64 : enable

void main()
{
  uint64_t foo = 0ul;
}
```

I got:

```
0:3(12): warning: extension `GL_ARB_gpu_shader_int64' unsupported in fragment shader
0:7(11): error: syntax error, unexpected NEW_IDENTIFIER, expecting ',' or ';'
```

glxinfo output:

```
name of display: :0.0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: SGI
server glx version string: 1.4
server glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile,
    [...]
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Haswell Mobile
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 18.0.5
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
    GL_3DFX_texture_compression_FXT1, GL_AMD_conservative_depth,
    [...]
```

Comment: I realized that the OpenGL vendor detected by glxinfo is Intel. Is this a sign that mesa is not detecting my AMD GPU ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.

Mesa was indeed using my integrated graphic chipset. By launching all the commands with the environment variable `DRI_PRIME=1`, I was able to directly use my GPU, thus enabling the asked extensions.

Howerver, I am not sure if setting this environment variable each time or globally is a good solution.